# file download in yii shows file not exist

Tags: php, pdf, csv, yii

I am trying to write a script in Yii for downloading files. 
view file is
`echo CHtml::link('Major Oilseeds: World Supply and Distribution.','downloadpdf', array('class'=>'btn btn-darkorange'));`
 and the controller code is 
 `$path = Yii::app()->request->hostInfo . Yii::app()->request->baseURL . '/download/Major_Oilseeds.csv';
 echo $path;
 if(file_exists($path)){
 Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile( 'Major_Oilseeds.csv' , file_get_contents($path) );
 }
 else{
      echo '<br>File not found';
 }` 
 the code `echo $path` dispalys the location as 
`http://localhost/projectv2/download/Major_Oilseeds.csv`
 and the download folder contains the file named "Major_Oilseeds.csv" but its always showing "File Not Found" Error. plz somebody help me to solve this. I have also tried the code 
 `$path = Yii::app()->request->hostInfo . Yii::app()->request->baseURL . '/download/Major_Oilseeds.csv';
 //  $filename = 'Major_Oilseeds.csv';
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; charset=UTF-8; filename="'.$path.'"');
 $utf8_content = mb_convert_encoding($content, "SJIS", "UTF-8");
 echo $utf8_content;
 Yii::app()->end();
 return;`
 but its also not working :-(

Comment: what is happening when you open the URL in your browser?

Comment: gets download the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_exists can only work with local files. In your case you are trying to use file_exists with a URL.

You can find a workaround here: https://www.php.net/file_exists (please search for "http" in this page)